# Suppose $P_0 $ and $P_1$ are singular distributions. Show that $N=[0,1]^2$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we want to test $H_0 :\mathbf{X} \sim P_0$ against $H_1 : \mathbf{X} \sim P_1$, where $P_0,P_1$ are two different laws of  $\mathbf{X}$.

Let $N$ be the set of points $(\alpha,\beta)$ for which there exists a test $\phi$ such that $E_{P_0}(\phi)=\alpha $ and $E_{P_{1}}(\phi)=\beta$.

Now suppose $P_0 $ and $P_1$ are singular distributions.

Show that $N=[0,1]^2$.

Now, all I could say that as $P_0$ and $P_1$ are singular, the supports of $P_0$ and $P_1$ are disjoint.

This means $\phi(\mathbf{X})=1(f_{0}(\mathbf{x})=0)$ has size $0$ and power $1$.

But what to do next? That is how can I show that $N$ is actually containing all points within the unit square?

Comment: If you draw a picture of $N$, this should be clear: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/440673/119261.

Comment: I know that $\phi(\mathbf{X})$ is the MP test. From here can I say $\{ (x,y): 0 \le x \le y < 1 \} \subseteq N$?

Comment: You know $(1,0)$ and $(0, 1)$ are in $N$. Of course $N$ always contains $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$. As discussed in the link, $N$ is convex.